# Swift - getting property by name crash with valueForUndefinedKey error

Tags: ios, swift

I have UIView extension that I want to use for adding gradient layer.
I know that I can't create a stored property of type `CAGradientLayer`(or any other type...) in the extension, so I want to create the gradientLayer property in the UIView itself (no in the extension) and than to check in the extension if this property exist.
So I ask for:

```
extension UIView
{
    private var gradientLayer:CAGradientLayer?
    {
        return value(forKey: "gradientLayer") as? CAGradientLayer
    }

    func addGradient()
    {
        guard gradientLayer != nil else
        {
            return
        }

        // do something with the layer
        }
}
```

When this property exist everything is ok, but otherwise the app crash with error:

> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant
>   for the key gradientLayer.

Is it possible to know if the property exist in this way without crashing the app?

Comment: Add some screenshots to know more about this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass UIView and implement [`valueForUndefinedKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1413457-valueforundefinedkey) so that it does something other than crash.

However, I would go about this an entirely different way; I'd store the extra information in the view's *layer*. A layer can store information under *any* key, and doesn't crash if you ask about a nonexistent key.